# can not run React Navigation demo

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. Please help.

Below code is from  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    return <Text>Hello, Navigation!</Text>;
  }
}

export default const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
});

// if you are using create-react-native-app you don't need this line
AppRegistry.registerComponent('SimpleApp', () => SimpleApp);
```

and it show

```
C:/Users/user/Desktop/AwesomeProject/App.js: Unexpected token (42:15) at C:\Users\user\Desktop\AwesomeProject\App.js:42:15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should remove `export default`

```
import React from 'react';
import {
 AppRegistry,
 Text,
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
 static navigationOptions = {
   title: 'Welcome',
 };
 render() {
  return <Text>Hello, Navigation!</Text>;
 }
}

const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({ // remove export default
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
});

// if you are using create-react-native-app you don't need this line

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SimpleApp', () => SimpleApp);
```